# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginForm' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have seen a lot of similar posts but nothing is working for me. So I will post it again with my code samples.
I am new to Spring MVC and trying to make a simple login form to work. But I am getting "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginForm' available as request attribute" again and again. 
Below is the index.jsp file having login form:

**Index.jsp**

```
<form:form action="login" method="post" modelAttribute="loginForm">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        <span>Username</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
        <form:input type="text" path="username" id="username"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        <span>Password</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
        <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">   
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2">                       
        <div id="msgbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-right">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <a id="notRegistered">Not registered? Please Sign Up</a>
        <button type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="sign-in-btn">Sign In</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

UserController is as below: **UserController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class UserController{
    @Autowired
    private UserManagementServices userManagementServices;

    //Login form data view/object mapping
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewLoginDetails(Model model) {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();    
        model.addAttribute("loginForm", userModel);

        return "index";
    }
    //Call login validation method using above view object mapping
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getValidateUserLogin(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") UserModel userModel , Map<String, Object> model) {
        UserIdentityLoginQuery userIdentityLoginQuery = new UserIdentityLoginQuery();
        //Get data from object created above and set login query arguments
        userIdentityLoginQuery.setUserName(userModel.getUsername());
        userIdentityLoginQuery.setPassword(userModel.getPassword());

        //Call service layer method to validate user
        userManagementServices.getValidateUserLogin(userIdentityLoginQuery);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

UserModel is as below: **UserModel.java**

```
public class UserModel {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    //Getters
    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>MME Application</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.xchanging.platform.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

</beans>
```

**spring-context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="userModel" class="com.grooming.platform.model.UserModel" />   
</beans>
```

**Folder Structure**

```
web
    src/main/java
        com.grooming.platform.controller
            UserController.java
        com.grooming.platform.model
            UserModel.java
    src
        main
            webapp
                WEB-INF
                    jsp
                        home.jsp
                    lib
                    mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
                    spring-context.xml
                    web.xml
                index.jsp
```

Any help will be highly appreciated as I am stuck here since days.

Thanks.

**Update**

Below is the error I am getting:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 173

170:                                <span>Username</span>
171:                            </div>
172:                            <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
173:                                <form:input type="text" path="username" id="username"/>
174:                            </div>
175:                        </div>
176:                        <div class="row text-center">


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginForm' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(index_jsp.java:717)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:653)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:235)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Updated **UserModel.java**

I have updated the UserModel to include setters as well but still no luck.

```
public class UserModel {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    //Getters
    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**Below is the server console on application startup**

```
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Password Manager\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;D:\Java\CodenTools\Tools\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Password Manager\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateA;.
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:web' did not find a matching property.
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 630 ms
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:45 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [113] milliseconds.
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jan 22 11:25:47 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml]
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 252 ms
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 22 11:25:47 IST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:48 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 22 11:25:47 IST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:48 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 22 11:25:47 IST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:48 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 603 ms
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2841 ms
Jan 22, 2015 11:25:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Comment: don't you have any setters in you UserModel object ?
That's the way the binding is made

Comment: please add the corresponding stacktrace too see where the exception is raised

Comment: Please check the update, I have added the stack trace.

Comment: @vincent I added the setters as well but still same error, please check the update for the error I am getting and the updated UserModel.java file.

Comment: which version of Spring do you use ?
I ask that because the following lines were not obvious to me
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
And there are deprecated since Spring 3.2.
I'm used to see
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
and wonder if this line doesn't replace the two above

Comment: @vincent I have changed it to <mvc:annotation-driven/> but still getting same error.  It seems controller is not mapped properly. Even when I comment out all the code in my controller class I am getting same error. Not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Move your index.jsp to WEB-INF/jsp directory and try access your application with the URL like this.

```
http://[hostname]:[Port]/[appcontext]/login.htm
```

Looks like your welcome-file list contains index.jsp as soon you try to access your application with the URL `http://[hostname]:[Port]/[appcontext]` index.jsp getting rendered to the browser this time no model attribute available.

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested and on accessing "http://[hostname]:[Port]/[appcontext]/login.htm" I am getting followinf error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'viewClass' is required and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'viewClass' is required.

Comment: viewClass is missing in your ViewResolver configuration can you add that and try. `<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this result because you are not using @BindingResult in your controller  You can correct it too 
ButYou are doing it wrong way.Use Spring security modules if you want to do it in easy way .Why to re invent wheel. It means you need not do any thing your self for security just use Spring API for security.

Just see some article about spring security with custom login form It is very easy I have used that in my project you can do it too.

All the best :)

Comment: Thanks for the info will certainly look into those. But it's not just about login, this is a sample application and I trying to get a hold of spring MVC by getting some data from the database for e.g. validating user from database in this case. Ideas? where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Had you tried to @BindingResult with your Post method ?

Comment: Do you mean like this "public String getValidateUserLogin(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") UserModel userModel, BindingResult results , Map<String, Object> model) {" ? If yes, still same error.

Comment: Yes i am really mean like this k, Also  I am not seeing any view resovler in your spring-servlet.xml Have you specified any view resolver there like                           <bean id="viewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
              <property name="prefix">
                 <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
              </property>
              <property name="suffix">
                 <value>.jsp</value>
              </property>
        </bean>

Comment: follow up this , First understand the flow than try to code.       http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/

Comment: Hi, please check mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml above, I have included a view resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Please changes your post method like that :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(
    @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
    BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

    //clear the command object from the session
    status.setComplete(); 

    //return form success view
    return "CustomerSuccess";

}
```

Comment: Hi, I have changed accordingly but no luck. It seems controller is not mapped properly. Even when I comment out all the code in my controller class I am getting same error. Not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have already run this code and its running in my side .Here are some changes

- Include commandName tag in your form like
- put index.jsp in to jsp folder of your project under Web-INF

controller code will look like  this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLogin(Model model) {
    UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
    model.addAttribute("loginForm", userModel);
    return "index";

}

@RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(
        @ModelAttribute("loginForm") UserModel userModel,
        BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        // if validator failed
        return "index";
    } else {

        return "home";
    }
}
```

Just run this basic version then you can extends .I am sure this time it will work:)

Comment: Did the same but now getting 404 not found error while accessing "http://localhost:8080/web/index.jsp". Pardon me if am sounding totally nube.

Comment: you are doing totaly wrong , just check your pom.xml and see entries     <artifactId> at top and than access page like this                                                        localhost:8080/<application name>/login

Comment: My application name is "web" so accessing localhost:8080/web/login gives 404 resource not available. Also on the console I am getting the warning - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web/login.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'.

Comment: Change this                                                                                           <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Change but no change still 404 resource not available. :(

Comment: Please attache your server console , when you start apache server

Comment: Hi Jitesh looking for your console it looks like you have done some thing worn g.Have you added the servlet mapping as i mentioned .Please update all post with latest code , than i see what is problem

Answer (score 0):

add view resolver like this and remove your one

`<beans:bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>`

Comment: I changed as above but now I am getting "org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 113; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'."

Comment: I think you can leave your project here and start up with fresh code , Use STS (spring tool suite ) It has already build template create new Spring mvc project there than add your jsp and contoller , that will be easy . If you get any problem using Sts than i am here